# Python - printing output of another script

Tags: python, colors, subprocess, output

I have a script that runs an another script.py with subprocess.
While it runs, I am parsing all the output for a text that indicates me what to do next.

```
def run_command(command):
    global p
    p = subprocess.Popen(command,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                            shell=True)
    return iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')

for line in run_command(command):
    sys.stdout.write(line)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    if "Nothing to show" in line:
        print "We can stop now"
        os.killpg(os.getpgid(p.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
```

Everything works fine. But the output of a script.py is colored, and I need to `sys.stdout.write(line)` with these original colors. Something like if I could use `subprocess.check_call` instead of `subprocess.Popen`. But how to parse the output in live time in that case?

I need to parse output of script.py, check it for a text, and print it with the original colors. First two actions I am getting done with the code above, but the last one I'm just can't find out. Is there any reasonable way?

Comment: but you are not setting/changing any colors here

Comment: Because another script makes output and sets colors of output lines. I am just running the script.py with some args, then I wait for some text to appear. And then I do some actions depends on a text I have parsed.